# Contributors not listed?

Tags: github

In the repository https://github.com/JdeH/Transcrypt of the open source project I started, only 3 contributors are shown.

This seems weird, since many people filed issues, some pull requests etc. I myself, committing almost daily to the project, am only mentioned in June.

My own visibility isn't very important, since I am the intiator. But the fact that all the other contributions aren't honoured isn't good for the project.

It gives the impression that it is very "private", while we're working on it with a group of regular contributors.

What am I doing wrong? Why do only these 3 show up, one of whom actually changed only 1 or 2 chars at the start of the project, several years ago?

I've been looking everywhere, but didn't find an answer. Must be missing something very obvious!

Comment: Perhaps you should raise this with GitHub support, not SO?

Comment: I;ve done that as well. Curious what they will answer... Thanks.